# AWS SageMaker Studio Lab - Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, sudo, amazon-sagemaker

I want to use AWS SageMaker Studio Lab for training some deep learning models but when I want to use my train.py SageMaker returns an error about stdnfile.

`OSError: sndfile library not found`

After that I found out I can fix that error with

`apt-get install libsndfile1 -y`

but every time when I try, I'm getting an error in the below.

`E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)`

I tried to use `sudo` because AWS SageMaker uses a Linux-based distro but It returns

`bash: sudo: command not found`

I tried `su` either and It wants a password from me. I tried my account password but it rejects.

Btw I saw an answer in the different question for `--allow-root` but It didn't work either.

p.s.: I use the same python file and `apt-get install libsndfile1 -y` in AWS SageMaker Studio and It worked well. AWS SageMaker servers type were **ml.m5.24xlarge** and **ml.t3.medium** (CPU Servers). I request a GPU Server in AWS SageMaker Studio but I'm still waiting (**ml.g4dn.xlarge**). On the other hand, I'm trying to train with GPU in AWS SageMaker Studio Lab.

Answer (score 0):

apt installs aren't supported yet for Studio Lab, see [GitHub issue #127](https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/issues/127).

SageMaker Studio, as you mentioned, allows installs - you should be able to get a fast launch GPU instance, please retry creating the app. Also, make sure your account has sufficient limits for GPU notebooks on Studio.